# Python parsing xml file correctly in heroku but not locally

Tags: python, xml, heroku

Im having a weird problem. I have a python projekt, which uses an XML File to store data. This file has special characters from the german language and gets parsed by ElementTree. When testing it locally, the special characters are not parsed correctly, but then testing it on heroku those characters are parsed correctly. What could be the problem here?
This is how I read and parse the file:

```
# Get the root of the XML File
# @return the root and tree
def get_root():
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as xml_file:
            tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        return tree.getroot(), tree
    except Exception:
        return None
```

Comment: Typical cases would be platform specific issues, different version of libraries used between heroku instance and your development machine!

Comment: @VivekHarikrishnan even if both the virtual enviroment and heroku use the same requirements file? Python version is the same and so are the libraries